# SQL Stored Procedure Error

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Perhaps I am not getting SQL Parameters correctly, but this doesn't work for me. Am I doing something wrong? I get a Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'AS' when I try to save this stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProc
AS
DECLARE @CID int

DELETE FROM Contacts 
WHERE ContactID=@CID

RETURN
```

Comment: Do you mean to pass `@CID` as a input parameter ? If Yes, then Avitus answer should work !

Comment: I would guess that your SQL is not as posted but rather has a name other than `MyProc`: either you've used a name that is a reserved word or you've omitted the proc name entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProc
   @CID int
AS
BEGIN

DELETE FROM Contacts 
WHERE ContactID=@CID

RETURN 

END
GO
```

Comment: @splattne - I have included return just because OP has it in his question. It is not redundant in this case.

Comment: @marc - It is not required. Everything up until `GO` is included in the definition even after a `BEGIN`... `END`

Comment: @Martin: ah, okay - counter-intuitive (at least for me), but you're (of course!) right...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to be:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProc
    @CID int
AS

Begin

DELETE FROM Contacts 
WHERE ContactID=@CID

end

GO
```

Comment: It appears that the op does need to change his statement, but nevertheless, he shouldn't get an error.

Comment: you are correct in that the proc shouldn't error but it's not performing as expected since @CID isn't set to a value in the problem.  I believe he's trying to get the parameter to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a procedure name

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_YOURSPROC
```

Edit:

You have a procedure with that name? If not you might need `CREATE` rather than `ALTER`. But that would give you an `invalid object name` error.

Should @CID be a parameter? otherwise it seems useless. But even if that is the case then you wouldn't get any error, it just wouldn't execute correctly.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProc
   @CID INT
AS
   DELETE FROM Contacts 
   WHERE ContactID=@CID
```

Comment: Copy and Paste typo wasnt the actual problem

Comment: yes I already have an a Stored Procedure in this example MyProc

Answer (score 0):

You've declared @CID *inside* the procedure. It should be declared a parameter though:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProc

    @CID int -- it's a parameter

AS

   DELETE 
   FROM Contacts 
   WHERE ContactID = @CID
```

If the stored procudure doesn't exist in the database yet, you'll have to use `CREATE PROCEDURE`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc

    @CID int -- it's a parameter

AS

   DELETE 
   FROM Contacts 
   WHERE ContactID = @CID
```